# logic apps - cannot be evaluated because property doesn't exist

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate, workflow-definition-language

In Logic Apps, I have an expression:

```
coalesce(triggerbody().data.job_id,triggerbody().resource_id,'error')
```

I basically want to get the first one that is not null, however one of these does not EXIST in the json payload. I get an error:

'The template language expression 'coalesce(triggerbody().data.job_id,triggerbody().resource_id,'error')' cannot be evaluated because property 'data' doesn't exist, available properties are 'transaction_id, event_type, event_time, resource, resource_id, account_id, resource_third_party_id, request_user_type, request_user_id'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

If data doesn't exist, that value should be "null" and resource_id used. Any ideas what the expression would look like to have that behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to access to a property of a null element:

```
coalesce(triggerbody().data.job_id,triggerbody().resource_id,'error')
```

As **triggerbody().data** is null, Logic App can't evaluate **triggerbody().data.job_id**, you should check first if **triggerbody().data** is null.

Comment: triggerbody().data doesn't exist in the payload deliberately- if it is not there, it needs to take from triggerbody().resource_id, but how do I do this.... I have tried if(equals(triggerbody().data, null), triggerbody().resource_id, triggerbody().data.job_id) but same error. Not sure how to check for undefined

Comment: Instead of use triggerbody().data, use triggerbody()?['data']. The question mark operator lets you reference null properties of an object without a runtime error. For example, you can use this expression to handle null trigger outputs:
@coalesce(trigger().outputs?.body?.property1, 'my default value')

Comment: Bingo. Thanks so much!